# Sub-setting list in Shiny using reactive input

Tags: r, list, dataframe, shiny, subset

I have a list of dataframes:

```
dflist<- list(df_unemploy = "df_unemploy", df_apl = "df_apl")
```

and a vector **indicator** created as:

```
indikator <- names(dflist)
```

and want to subset from this list each dataframe using **checkbox**:

```
checkboxGroupInput('indicator', 
                     'Choose df:', 
                     names(dflist),
                     selected = names(dflist[1]))..
```

In my **server.R** I am trying something like this:

```
indicator <- reaction$indicator
new_df <- dflist['indicator']
new_df <- as.data.frame(new_df)
return(new_df)
```

but I get **NULL** value or the warning:
***Warning: Error in datatable: 'data' must be 2-dimensional (e.g. data frame or matrix)***

which I tried to repair using :

```
new_df <- as.data.frame(new_df)
```

My full code for **server.R** is:

```
library(shiny)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)


source("do_data.R")  # here dflist created
source("do_label.R") # here indicator created

# Load the dataset
loadData <- function() {
dflist <- dflist
return(dflist)
}

# Shared data
globalData <- loadData()

# Get raw data
getTable <- function(dflist, reaction){
indicator <- reaction$indicator
new_df <- dflist[['indicator']]
new_df <- as.data.frame(new_df)
return(new_df)   
}

shinyServer(function(input, output) { # server is defined within these      parentheses

localFrame <- globalData  

getReaction <- reactive({
return(list(indicator = input$indicator
))  })

output$ex1 = DT::renderDataTable({print(getTable(localFrame,  getReaction()))}, options = list(dom = 'Rlrtp',searchHighlight = TRUE , pageLength = 15, language = list(search = 'Filter:'), extensions = 'KeyTable')) # output table
```

})

What I am missing here?

Regards

Comment: try `dflist[['indicator']]` that is with 2 brackets on each side.

Comment: Thx John, not working. Result is 
    data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows

Comment: Thx I posted my full server. R file. the idea is to subset list by user selection and then work with each part for different purposes

Comment: Ok solved. The idea is to change dflist<- list(df_unemploy = df_unemploy, df_apl = df_apl)

Answer (score 0):

Subset was not working because when list was defined list objects were saved as string when in fact all of them are datasets.

I changed :

```
dflist<- list(df_unemploy = df_unemploy, df_apl = df_apl)
```

and combined with John Paul helpful answer:

```
dflist[['indicator']]
```

everything worked fine.

Regards

Comment: Good to know you solved your issue. Since the problem was a typo, this answer is unlikely to help another user, si I'd suggest you delete both of them